# How can I filter Nodes in Neo4j Based on properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have plotted 2 graphs on same Neo4j

```
Type 1: Nodes that have instance as **defaultInstance**
Type 2: Nodes that have instance as **masterInstance**
```

Some nodes are present in both the instances with same name. I need to find out those which are present in default instance but not in masterinstance.
You can imagine like defaul instance is a superset and master instance is a subset.
What I need is complement of both the instances.

I hope the problem is clear.

I tried the below Cypher Query

```
MATCH (t1:table{instance:"defaultInstance" }) exists(
MATCH (t2:table{instance = "masterinstance"})for t1.name)
RETURN t1.name AS name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `defaultInstance`, where no `masterInstance` is present. Try this:

```
MATCH (t1:table{instance: "masterinstance"})
WITH collect(t1.name) AS masterInstanceNames
MATCH (t1:table{instance: "defaultInstance"})
WHERE NOT t1.name IN masterInstanceNames
RETURN t1.name AS name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 overlapping "kinds" of `Table` node, you should use additional labels, say `Default` and `Master`. A node can have multiple labels.

For example, if all `Master` tables are `Default` tables but not vice versa, here is how you might create a `Master` node:

```
CREATE (:Table:Default:Master {name: 'Alice'})
```

and here is how to create a non-`Master` node:

```
CREATE (:Table:Default {name: 'Ted'})
```

Once you have instituted the above data model, you can find the names of all `Default` nodes (including ones that are also `Master` nodes) this way:

```
MATCH (t:Default) RETURN t.name
```

Or, if you only want the names of `Master` nodes:

```
MATCH (t:Master) RETURN t.name
```

*NOTE: If all `Table` nodes are `Default` nodes and vice versa, then you should get rid of one of those labels.*